# Why onClick() Method of ClickableSpan is called twice in android

Tags: android, textview

`onClick` method is called twice, so when back from `SecondActivity.class` it will again reload it. I have a `TextView` named `postTextView` in which `See More` is clickable.

Where:
`R.string.readMore = See More`.

Here is the code which I've used.

```
String mTitleBody = Html.fromHtml(postBodyText).toString().substring(0, 150).trim();

mTitleBody = mTitleBody.concat("..." + mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.readMore)).replaceAll("<img.+?>|<IMG.+?>", "").replaceAll("\n", "<br/>");
int index1 = Html.fromHtml(mTitleBody).toString().trim().length() -
        mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.readMore).length();
int index2 = Html.fromHtml(mTitleBody).toString().trim().length();

postTextView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
postTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
postTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(mTitleBody), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
Spannable mySpannable = (Spannable) postTextView.getText();
ClickableSpan myClickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      Log.d("FirstClass", "onClick");

      Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SecondActivity.class);
      (mContext).startActivity(intent);
      ((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

    }

    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
      super.updateDrawState(ds);
      ds.setUnderlineText(false);
      ds.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.body_text_3));
    }
};
mySpannable.setSpan(myClickableSpan, index1, index2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Can anyone help me here, Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is this source code located? in which method?

Comment: dump your spans to make sure they are not duplicated: `TextUtils#dumpSpans()`

Comment: How did you fix this? even I am getting the same issue now.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the autolink property in the TextView then you need to set the TextView to not be focusable after setting the movement method.

To do this add the following line after `postTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`:

```
postTextView.setFocusable(false);
```

An explanation is in the second paragraph from the Android setMovementMethod documentation:

> Sets the MovementMethod for handling arrow key movement for this
>   TextView. This can be null to disallow using the arrow keys to move
>   the cursor or scroll the view.
>
> Be warned that if you want a TextView with a key listener or movement
>   method not to be focusable, or if you want a TextView without a key
>   listener or movement method to be focusable, you must call
>   View.setFocusable(boolean) again after calling this to get the
>   focusability back the way you want it.

Link to the documentation: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setMovementMethod(android.text.method.MovementMethod)

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem with double invocation of the `onClick`. But how to keep text in the TextView selectable?

Answer (score 5):

I had this exact same issue, it was because I had the *"autolink: true"* property in the respective view, removing it helped.